# Move popup window out of screen

Tags: android

Hello i have this code to show popup window...

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams parameters = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            (width/100)*50, height, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
parameters.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER;
parameters.x = (width/100)*50;
parameters.y = 0;
```

But i need to show it out of screen...
When i set x position to more then windows size it's stuck at corner and not go over screen...

Thanks.

Edit: Because some people don't know what i mean.. i mean half outside screen not full..

Comment: not sure i understand the purpose of showing it outside the screen (which is equivalent to not being visible)

Comment: Show it out of the screen? that's equivalent to not showing I guess..

Comment: Half outside screen...

Comment: BTW (width/100)*50 is actually a half of width, so it's more readable (width / 2)

Comment: Place your view inside a layout. Place the layout in Windowmanager. Now if you move the view out of layout bounds, it will move out. It won't stuck at border.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add one more flag which is `flag_layout_no_limits`

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams parameters = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            (width/100)*50, height, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);  

parameters.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER;
parameters.x = (width/2);
parameters.y = 0;
```

Comment: you need to add one more flag flag_layout_no_limits

Comment: Thanks this is what i need.